# Full URL of xsd schemaLocation in WSDL on WSO2 ESB EI

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've created a proxy service on WSO2 and the publish wsdl has references to some XSD files in the registry.

The WSDL is opening fine, but the referenced XSD files are using relative path. I'd like them to be with full url.

Cheking the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Working+with+Proxy+Services) I saw there is this parameter:

showAbsoluteSchemaURL, that when setting to true it will make the references to be displayed with a full url.

But even using this, it is displaying the relative url.

Does anyone has made something similar in wso2 esb?

Thanks,